# Checking for NullPointerException, correctness or personal belief?

Tags: java

In my code, I am making a lot of checks for `null` so that I don't get a `NullPointerException` usually i am just doing like this:

```
if(variable != null){
    //do something with the variable
}
```

Is the following better in any way or is it just a matter or personal belief?

```
if( !variable.equals(null) ){
    //do something with the variable
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to make this check?

Btw I do have done my research already but I cant seem to find concrete evidence to prove either point.

P.S This is a **NOT** duplicate of [Avoiding != null statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements), on that the best answer is that you should either use Assert, which cannot be used to run code rather than just display a message, or actually throw the exception which I dont want either. This post is addressing a different issue of the same subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding != null statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements)

Comment: How would the second be better? It will throw a NullPointerException when `variable` is null

Comment: @cricket_007 that is true, but my aim was, to show that i meant to use `.equals`

Comment: @you could use [Object#equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) like `Objects.equals(null, variable)`. But in fact that would be the same as `variable == null` just written different.

Comment: I think the actual solution here might depend on how you want to handle the value when you do find null (or not). Like using an `Optional`, for example

Comment: I always prefer correctness over personal belief. Especially other people's personal belief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if(!variable.equals(null) ){
     //do something with the variable
 }
```

If variable is null NPE occurs. First method is far better.

EDIT:
Using Optional:
Consider that you have `Person` object and want to `getSalary()`. Unfortunately age can be null - in that case you want default value. You can do `Integer salary = Optional.ofNullable(person.getSalary()).orElse(2000)`. It will return salarty from person or 2000 in case salary is null.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Is there maybe a better way than the first one then to do it?

Comment: Agree - you should use this if(variable != null){}

Comment: There is not better way to checking if something is null or not. Based on you need you can consider using of `Optional` from Java8 or just trying to not passing `null` values in you code.

Comment: @ByeBye i am trying not to, but you never know ^^ could you provide an example with the `Optional` that you mentioned?

Comment: consider that you have `Person` object and want to `getSalary()`. unfortunately `age` can be null - in that case you want default value. You can do `Integer salary = Optional.ofNullable(person.getSalary()).orElse(2000)`. It will return salarty from person or 2000 in case salary is null.

Comment: thats a very good answer, please add that in your answer post.

Answer (score 2):

As others already said, the variant

```
if(!variable.equals(null))
```

can NPE itself when variable is null. Furthermore, you have to be sure that the equals method also is null-safe for all object types you use. Thus, if you absolutely need to check, use ==.

As for better solutions (we're going opinion-based here): I think that this ecessive null-checking is a sign of brittle software and suboptimal interface definition. What I currently try to do more and more is use the javax.validation annotation @NotNull to harden my interfaces and get rid off all these runtime checks:

```
private @NotNull String getName() {...} // guaranteed not to return null
...
if(getName() == null) { // superfluos, your IDE gives a shout if configurd correctly
   ...
}
```

... give it a shot :)

**Edit** (as an answer to the comment, as I need code-formatting):

Here's a complete cut&paste-example from my current eclipse setup:

```
package stuff;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class Try3 {
   public @NotNull String getName() { return ""; }

   public void test() {
      if(getName() == null)
         System.out.println("Cannot happen due to contract");
   }
}
```

Ensure, that the imported type is indeed javax.validation.constraints.NotNull (as other frameworks also have a NotNull annotation, which may be defined in a different way). For eclipse, you also have to check "Enable annotation-based null analysis" in the project settings under JavaCompiler / Errors/Warnings and customize the annotations to use, as eclipse defaults to some home-brewed annotations. The customization can be accessed via the link "Configure" after the checkbox for using default annotations in the same settings page. Hope that helps!

Comment: I did try what you recommended but when trying to add the `@NotNull` to the method, i am getting a `The annotation @NotNull is disallowed for that location`..... And i have it the same way as yours, `private @NotNull String getStr()
  {
    return "";
  }`

Comment: for some reason, i keep getting errors, also the IDE keeps on asking to change the import with the `@com.esotericsoftware.kryo.NotNull`

Comment: If it is a maven project, add the dependency javax.validation.validation-api (1.1.0.Final) - otherwise, check where you get that library.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [java.util.Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) from Java 8.

Very nice examples are on [JavaCodeGeeks](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/optional/java-8-optional-example/).

Optional is usually used in [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) lambdas for "functional-style operations".

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

```
public void calculate(Class variable) {
    Assert.notNull(variable, "variable was null");
    //calculations
}
//and
if (variable == null) {
    //bad
} else {
    calculate(variable);
}
```

The second one is the most common one. If your variable is a `String` consider using `Guava.StringUtils` with it's fantastic `isBlank` method which checks if the `String` is `null` or `""`

Summarizing:

```
if (variable == null) {
    //bad
} else {
    //good
}
```

The above is standard approach. The better approach will be:

```
private boolean isNull(Class variable) {
    return variable == null;
}

if (isNull(variable)) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: can the one with the `Assert.` be used to do something (i mean run some code)  except display a message?

Comment: It will just throw exception when variable is `null` with message.

Comment: It throws an exception on null.

Comment: So it cannot be used in conditional if-else statements

Comment: @hedgehog check my update. One is used for making contract that `variable` definitely won't be a `null`. The other should be used before calculations assuming notNull.

Comment: Assert, doesnt help much though, because it just lets you display a message, it doesnt let you run some other code instead.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do call the below method all the time which checks for nullpointer exception

```
public static boolean isAvailable(Object data) {
        return ((data!=null) && (data.toString().trim().length() > 0));
    }
```

Comment: hmmm possible answer, but i think its not efficient as if you need other situation controls you wont be able to configure.... thanks though